# Tengo el siguiente error Unable to import 'django.contrib'pylint(import-error)

Tags: python, django, vscode

Hola hice la instalacion de virtualenv y django correctamente pero a la hora de configurar el views.py y el urls.py me da el siguiente error.

`Unable to import 'django.shortcuts'pylint(import-error)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución es configurar el path de instalación de python dentro de VScode. Pulsa (CTRL + ,) luego ve a Workspace/Extensions/pylint y cambia la ruta donde se encuentre la instalación de Python.

Comment: muchísimas gracias la solución funciono